# When is a unitary group over a ring of integers dense?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $ SU_n(O_d) $ denote an integral unitary group of $ n \times n $ matrices over a totally real number field $ K_d:=\mathbb{Q}(\cos(\frac{2\pi }{d})) $ where $ O_d $ is the ring of integers of $ K_d $.

Question:

For which $ d $ is $ SU_n(O_d) $ dense (with respect to the manifold topology) in the full group of $ n \times n $ unitary matrices $ SU_n $?

And is it true that for every $ d $ either $ SU_n(O_d) $ is finite or $ SU_n(O_d) $ is dense in $ SU_n $?

Context:

For $ d=1,2 $ then $ O_d = \mathbb{Z} $ and $ SU_n(O_d) $ is finite.

For an example where $ SU_n(O_d) $ is dense in $ SU_n $ consider $ n=2,d=16 $ then the matrices
$$
\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \overline{\zeta_{16}} & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta_{16} \end{bmatrix}
$$
generate a dense subgroup of $ SU_2 $. Similar examples exist for $ n $ higher powers of $ 2 $ (and one can still choose $ d=16 $).

I could have asked the same question about $ U_n(O_d) $. But I think that $ U_n(O_d) $ would never be dense in $ U_n $ because if it was then the image of $ U_n(O_d) $ in $ U_1 $ under the determinant mapping would also be dense. But I don't think that's possible since the determinant of a matrix in $ U_n(O_d) $ is in $ U_1(O_d) $ which is finite and thus not dense in $ U_1 $.

Comment: The integral unitary group is always finite. In the dense example you give, the first matrix is not integral. If you extend the question to S-integral conditions, the answer is yes by the strong approximation theorem for S-arithmetic groups.

Comment: @Aurel I see, then I need to learn more about S-arithmetic groups. Can you explain more what the (proper) definition of the integral unitary group is and why it must be finite? Is it generally true that an arithmetic subgroup of a compact group is always finite? And only S-arithmetic subgroups can be dense?

Comment: Well, the integral unitary group is the group of unitary matrices that have integral coefficients... Every arithmetic group is discrete when embedded in the correct product of Lie groups, so if this product is compact you get a finite group. No, arithmetic groups can also be dense, if you omit an embedding into a Lie group that is not compact.